# How to execute three terminal scripts in three new tabs from Applescript?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, script, applescript

I have the following apple script top execute three commands in different terminals. Is it possible to (1) combine this script to make it more efficient and (2) open in different terminal tabs instead of different windows?

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

# Terminal 1
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "
        cd folder1 &&
        command1"
end tell

# Terminal 2
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "
        cd folder2 &&
        command2"
end tell

# Terminal 3
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "
        cd folder2 &&
        command2"
end tell
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'different terminals'?

Comment: @Tetsujin currently when I run this script, three terminal windows open, each executing their own script. I want them to open in new tabs instead. Just updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just send the key command to open a new tab, then direct your script to this new tab. You don't need to `activate` each time, once it's at the front.
Here I've substituted `echo hello` so it's safe to test.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "echo hello" in selected tab of the front window
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "echo hello" in selected tab of the front window
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "echo hello" in selected tab of the front window
end tell
```

You could run a loop, but it doesn't seem worth it when each new script is different [& we don't actually know what it might do]. This contains no error checking. You might need to add delays or a presence-check to make sure it runs smoothly.